# Create a shopping cart class

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to create a program with "Item" and "Shopping Cart" as 2 separate classes.

Using a "Shopping Cart" I should be able to add/remove/update and get the total cost the items listed in "Items" in the cart, but I'm unsure of how to access the "Items" dictionary and add it to the shopping cart list.

```
l_items = ({"teddy": {'name': 'Teddy',
                      "desc": "toy",
                      "price": 3.21},
            "sweet": {'name': 'Rolo',
                      "desc": 'chocolate',
                      'price': 1.21}})


class Item:

    def __init__(self, name, desc, price):
        self._name = name
        self._desc = desc
        self._price = price
        self._stock = len(l_items)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name


class ShoppingCart:

    def __init__(self, item=[]):
        self._item = item

    def add_item(self, new):
        self._item.append(new)

    def remove_item(self, remove):
        self._item.remove(remove)

    def update_item(self, update):
        pass

    def view(self):
        return self

    def getTotalCost(self):
        total = 0
        for i in self._item:
            total += i.getTotalCost()

    def reset(self):
        self._item = []

    def isEmpty(self):
        return len(self._items) == 0
```

Comment: Beware of `item=[]` , see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Please do this first!

As pointed out by @ThierryLathuille, it would be wise of you to rewrite the constructor of the class `ShoppingCart`, as shown in the code section.

**Also**, the `__repr__` method in the `Item` class seems incorrect. You probably wanted to return `self._name` instead of `self.name`, as in the code you have shared `self.name` does not exist in the `Item` class.

### Code

```python3
class Item:
    ...  # The rest of your class's contents
    def __repr__(self):
        return self._name
```

```python3
class ShoppingCart:
    def __init__(self, item=None):
        if item is None:
            self._item = []
        else:
            self._item = item
    
    ...  # The rest of your class's contents
```

**Note:** In your code, doing `item=[]` in the `ShoppingCart` constructor's parameter list does not mean that, each time the constructor is called, a new list will be created and set as the default value of the `item` parameter.

What actually happens is that it will create and (re)use only a single shared instance of the list object across all constructor calls, giving you the behaviour you may not expect, such as the shopping cart list being shared among different users.

## Interacting with items and your shopping cart

Now, coming to your question, you could do something like this:

##### Adding items to your cart

```python3
cart = ShoppingCart()  # Creating an instance of shopping cart
for itemType in l_items:
    item = l_items[itemType]  # Getting the dictionary containing the item's data
    itemObject = Item(item['name'], item['desc'], item['price'])  # Creating an instance of Item
    cart.add_item(itemObject)  # Adding the item object to the instance of ShoppingCart
```

Answer (score 0):

Default values in python act like static variables. There is only one default object created for any number of Method Invocations.